# Odd dpi setting when using large fonts in Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Windows 7, C#, .Net 4.5.2:

In an application I need to detect the current system setting for text size, for the current host machine. I have (full disclosure!) pinched the following code fragment from another posting:

```
        var form = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();
        Graphics gfx = form.CreateGraphics();
        userDPI = (int)gfx.DpiX;
```

This seems to be a common approach to the problem, and if my Windows System text size is set to "smaller fonts (default)", this reports userDPI as 96. If I set my Windows System text size to "medium - 125%" (and then re-login) the fragment reports userDPI as 120 (which is 125% of 96dpi). So far so good.

However if I set my Windows System text size to "Larger - 150%", the code fragment actually reports userDPI as 96 (which is definitely not 150% of 96dpi!) where instead I would expect a result of 144.

The screen text size when using larger text is clearly much bigger than either of the alternatives, so I know I have definitely changed the system settings as expected.

So how do I *reliably* determine the current system setting for text size?

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone else who encounters the same issue, the answer seems to be to get it direct from the registry:

```
    userDPI = (int)Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop", "LogPixels", 0);
```